# Python Pillow opening 1-bit depth files with 8 bits

Tags: python, bigdata, python-imaging-library, pixel

I've got about 7GB of single-bit depth images (black and white BMP files), around 59 gigapixels total, which I need to paste together into a single square image.
My system has 64GB RAM, so I figured this shouldn't be a problem to load all images at once, then create a new output image (should be the same size/resource-load), and paste the sub-images into it. Finally saving it to disk.

Well, watching `top`, I see after my images are loaded, the program is consuming 56GB RAM (i.e. `7GB * 8`). During the pasting operation, the program gets killed.

Can I somehow change the Pillow `open` call to open in the native depth? Is there another image processing library someone might recommend instead (other languages are acceptable if that's the only obvious route...).

Here's the code:

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
from rectpack import newPacker, PackingMode
import rectpack.packer
from PIL import Image, PILLOW_VERSION
dirname = 'output_12_15'
files = sorted(os.listdir(dirname))
images = []
num_pixels = 0
for i, file in enumerate(files[1:]):
    filepath = os.path.join(dirname, file)
    img = Image.open(filepath)
    images.append(img.copy())
    img.close()
    width, height = images[-1].size
    num_pixels += width*height
    if not i%1000:
        print(i)
print('number of total pixels: {}'.format(num_pixels))
edge_len = math.ceil(num_pixels**(1/2))
theorhetical_num_images_wide = math.ceil(edge_len/1366.)
target_width = (theorhetical_num_images_wide+1)*1366
target_height = target_width

packer = newPacker(mode=PackingMode.Offline, sort_algo=rectpack.packer.SORT_NONE, rotation=False)
# Add the rectangles to packing queue
for img in images:
    packer.add_rect(*img.size)
packer.add_bin(target_width, target_height)
print('starting to pack')
packer.pack()
print('finished packing, starting to paste image together')

if len(packer[0])!=len(images):
    print('packer failed, bin was too small!')
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
else:
else:
    max_y = 0
    max_x = 0
    blank = Image.new("1", (target_width,target_height))
    for i, rect in enumerate(packer[0]):
        x = rect.x
        y = rect.y
        w = rect.width
        h = rect.height
        if y+h>max_y:
            max_y = y+h
        if x+w>max_x:
            max_x = x+w
        blank.paste(images[i], (x,y))
    print('max_x {} max_y {} target_h {}'.format(max_x, max_y, target_height))
    blank = blank.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE)
    blank.save("59MP.bmp", "BMP")
```

**UPDATE 1**: I moved the code to another system with 256GB RAM, and found a bug after things got a little further (into the last FOR loop). But then it crashes again with this traceback:

```
0
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000
6000
number of total pixels: 59926682272
starting to pack
finished packing, starting to paste image together
max_x 247246 max_y 247243 target_h 247246
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stitch_bmps.py", line 75, in <module>
    blank.save("59MP.bmp", "BMP")
  File "/home/nmz787/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2084, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/nmz787/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py", line 332, in _save
    + o32(offset)  # reserved
  File "/home/nmz787/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/_binary.py", line 91, in o32le
    return pack("<I", i)
struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

**UPDATE 2**: added a `pdb.set_trace()` call in the `BmpImagePlugin` file just before the error:

```
(Pdb) image
7641879368
(Pdb) offset+image
7641879430
(Pdb) (offset+image)<4294967295
False
(Pdb) (image)<4294967295
False
```

Sooo, I guess this is saying that BMP format, or the implementation PIL has for BMP, doesn't support such large images?

Comment: If you open all the input images and the output image at the same time, you will double the memory pressure. Why not create the output image and load a single input image at a time and paste it into the correct position before closing it and opening the next? Or do the job in two halves?

Comment: It highly likely PIL converts 1-bit per pixel image to 8-bit internally to make per-pixel operations much faster. The alternative would require a tremendous amount of masking and bit-twiddling to accomplish in a reasonable amount of time. That will likely be the case for most if not all other packages as well.

Comment: moved the code to a new system with 4x the RAM, now I've got an `Exception`

Comment: added PDB trace info, showing the image variable in PIL is larger than 32-bits (2**32)

Comment: The size of the BMP is given in a 32-bit integer in the BMP header at offset 2 bytes, so it cannot exceed 32-bits... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format Maybe try saving as a PNG file instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this causes complications for further downstream operations that I now have to consider.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html,
there is only an image mode

> `1` (1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)

but not one with 8 pixels per byte.

So it seems this is not possible with Pillow.

Comment: hmm, I created these images with Pillow, so just now tried using some of the code I had there, replacing `images.append(img.copy())` with `images.append(img.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE))` and even adding `del img` after the `img.close()`...  but yeah, same RAM load. Thanks for the specifics.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I am on no more questions ban, sorry to bother. Does '1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)' means that 1bit images have a max size ?? (smaller than mode 'L':  (8-bit pixels, black and white))